# TypeError: board[row] is undefined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

Boa  Tarde,

Venho pedir ajuda para um projecto que estou a fazer em JavaScript.
O meu objetivo neste momento é, após criar um tabuleiro de jogo, movimentar as peças.

Neste momento não estou a conseguir progredir por causa deste erro:
TypeError: board[row] is undefined ( linha 115 JS).
No entanto a variável já foi declarada e usada anteriormente.

```js
"use strict";
var tableOfGame;
var turtleBoard;
var jewels;
var wall;
var players;
var position;
var p1;
var moveUp;
var boardSize;


function main() {
    boardSize = [];
    turtleBoard = createTurtleBoard(8); //fazer o tabuleiro
    jewels = jewelsInsert(turtleBoard);  //inserir a joia precisa do tamanho do tabuleiro
    wall = wallInsert(jewels, 10);       //inserir muros no tabuleiro precisa da joias, que ja tem tabuleiro e ainda o numero de muros
    players = addPlayers(turtleBoard, 4); //adicionar jogadores às posiçoes iniciais
    tableOfGame = boardOnScreen(players); //passar para a window as linhas em diferentes colunas
    position = playerFinder(tableOfGame, 'p1');
    moveUp = moveUp(tableOfGame, position)
    document.getElementById("game").innerHTML = tableOfGame; //passar para o html

    function createTurtleBoard(boardSize) {
        let table = [boardSize];
        for (var row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
            table[row] = [boardSize];
            for (var column = 0; column < boardSize; column++) {
                table[row][column] = 0;
                

            }
        }
        console.log(table)
        return table
    }

    function boardOnScreen(boardSize) {
        let board = ''
        for (var row = 0; row < boardSize.length; row++) {
            for (var column = 0; column < boardSize.length; column++) {
                board += boardSize[row][column] + ' '
            }
            board = board + '</br>'
        }
        return board

    }

    function jewelsInsert(boardSize) {
        let rowA = (boardSize.length) / 2;
        let rowB = (boardSize.length) / 2 - 1;
        let columnA = (boardSize.length) / 2;
        let columnB = (boardSize.length) / 2 - 1;
        boardSize[rowA][columnA] = 'J';
        boardSize[rowB][columnB] = 'J';
        boardSize[rowA][columnB] = 'J';
        boardSize[rowB][columnA] = 'J';
        return boardSize
    }


    function addPlayers(boardSize, numPlayers) {
        let position = boardSize.length - 1;
        switch (numPlayers) {
            case 1:
                boardSize[0][0] = 'P1';
                break;
            case 2:
                boardSize[0][0] = 'P1';
                boardSize[position][0] = 'P2';
                break;
            case 3:
                boardSize[0][0] = 'P1';
                boardSize[position][0] = 'P2';
                boardSize[position][position] = 'P3';
                break;
            default:
                boardSize[0][0] = 'P1';
                boardSize[position][0] = 'P2';
                boardSize[position][position] = 'P3';
                boardSize[0][position] = 'P4';
                break;
        }
        return boardSize
    }


    function wallInsert(boardSize, numWall) {
        let size = boardSize.length - 1;
        let count = 0;
        while (count < numWall) {
            let column = Math.floor((Math.random() * size))
            let row = Math.floor((Math.random() * size))
            if (boardSize[row][column] === 0) {
                boardSize[row][column] = 'W'
                count++
            }
        }
        return boardSize
    }

    function playerFinder(boardSize, player) {
        let board = boardSize;
        for (let row = 0; row <= board.length; row++)
            for (let column = 0; column <= board.length; column++)
                if (board[row][column] == player) {
                    let position = [row, column]

                    return position
                }
    }



    function moveUp(boardSize, player) {
        var n = boardSize.length
        for (let row = 0; row <= n; row++) {
            for (let column = 0; column <= n; column++) {
                if (boardSize[row][column] === player && boardSize[row - 1][column] === 0) {
                    boardSize[row][column] = 0
                    boardSize[row - 1][column] = player
                }
                return player
            }
        }
    }
}
window.onload = main
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="style.css">    
    
</head>
<body id="total">
    
    <h3>Game</h3>
    <p id="game"></p>
    <table id="tableOfGame" class = "panel">
        <tr><td></td><td><button id='UP'>UP</button></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td><button id = 'Left'>Left</button></td><td></td><td><button id = 'Right'>Right</button></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><button id = "Down">Down</button></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
    
    <script id ="js" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Se alguem conseguisse ajudar agradecia imenso. Apesar de poder ser uma dúvida parva, é o que de momento está a travar o meu progresso.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você deve se certificar de que `boardSize.legth > 0`, do contrário você não poderá percorrê-lo adequadamente em `boardOnScreen(boardSize)`. O primeiro método que você chama é `createTurtleBoard(8)` que faz um `for (var row = 0; row < boardSize; row++)` - perceba que está faltando o `.lenght` explicitamente, daí ele vai considerar 0. É isso mesmo o que você quer? Porque o boardSize é inicializado (antes) como um array vazio. Tudo isso considerando o `main()` como *bootstrap*. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Eu tentei fazer isso, mas deixava de ter tabuleiro e ficava só com um array de elemento [8].
Em vez disso, tirei o length da função do erro e já me apresentou a matriz que faz de tabuleiro. 
Obrigado mais uma vez.